# SilverStripe 3.1 custom form templating - how can I output a single action field without looping through all Actions?

Tags: forms, field, action, silverstripe, templating

Hello SilverStripe Community,

Forgive me if this is an elementary question, but in a custom form template, how can I output individual action fields without looping through all of them?  Is there a way of doing that?

For example, when it comes to the form fields, I can loop through them with this:

```
<% loop $Fields %>
    $Field
<% end_loop %>
```

OR I can output individual form fields like this:

```
$Fields.dataFieldByName(Email)
```

Is there something similar for form actions?
I know I can loop through them with:

```
<% loop $Actions %>
    $Field
<% end_loop %>
```

but as I have one huge client form with several action buttons located in various positions in the form, I need to be able to output the action buttons individually with a great degree of control.
The only way I know how to achieve this at the moment is to manually create the markup for each action throughout the form, like this:

```
<button id="{$FormName}_action_doLogin" class="action button-login" value="Login" name="action_doLogin" type="submit">
    <span>Login</span>
</button>
```

...but I'm looking for something like:

```
$Actions.dataFieldByName(Login)
```

OR

```
$Actions.Field(Login)
$Actions.Field(AddressLookup)
```

etc.

Does something like that exist in SilverStripe templating for Actions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all actions are prefixed with "action_"

so function

```
$Actions.dataFieldByName(Login)
```

works, but you need to call it as :

```
$Actions.dataFieldByName(action_Login)
```

Comment: Thanks, @martin-rázus, that worked.  I was sure I tried this before, but after seeing your answer, I tried it again successfully.